# Is it possible to rearrange and recreate a single disk partition in a raw image file?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, ext4, disk-image, parted

Host: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Current status: Raw image file has 2 partitions, p1: boot and p2: rootfs.

```
Disk original.img.bak: 3.25 GiB, 3487742976 bytes, 6811998 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xddbefb06

Device            Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
original.img.bak1 *      2048  526335  524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
original.img.bak2      526336 6811963 6285628    3G 83 Linux
```

Goal: Create a third persistence partition, and locate it as the second partition (p2) and change the rootfs partition location to be the third partition (p3).

This is added into a script so e.g. no GUI tools cannot be used, nor any special stdin requirements.

Resulting image would be: p1 boot, p2 persistence, p3 rootfs

How I think the process in my head (the 'algorithm'):

```
Write p2 (rootfs) into a file with dd
Remove p2 from the partition table (remove partition)
Unmount
Truncate the image file unallocated space left from the removed rootfs partition
Allocate space for new partition (persistence) + extra empty space => append to the image file as zeroes
Mount
Create the new partition (now p2)
Create the filesystem
Check the filesystem
Unmount
Allocate space for the original rootfs partition + extra empty space
Mount
Create a new partition for the rootfs
Write the rootfs image file over the partition with dd
=> TODO somehow fix the partition table to think where the correct start and end sectors are
Check the filesystem is ok
```

The script I made for this process:

```
imgFile='original.img'
imgFileBak="${imgFile}.bak"

rootImgFile='rootfs.img'

zeroDev='/dev/zero'

partNumBoot=1
partNumRoot=2
partNumPersist=3

partNumBootNew=1
partNumRootNew=3
partNumPersistNew=2

rm -vf ${imgFile}
cp -v ${imgFileBak} ${imgFile}

dev=$(losetup -f)
losetup -P "${dev}" ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

dd status=progress conv=sparse if="${dev}p${partNumRoot}" of=${rootImgFile}

sync
sleep 1

sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}
parted -s -a opt "${dev}" rm ${partNumRoot}
sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

partEnd=$(sfdisk -s -l -o End "${dev}" | tail -1)
partEnd=$(( partEnd + 1 ))

losetup -d "${dev}"
losetup -D

sync
sleep 1

stat ${imgFile}
truncate --size $(( partEnd * 512 )) ${imgFile}
stat ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

dd status=progress if=${zeroDev} bs=1MB count=256 >> ${imgFile}
dd status=progress if=${zeroDev} bs=1b count=64 >> ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

dev=$(losetup -f)
losetup -P "${dev}" ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}
parted -s -a opt "${dev}" mkpart primary ext4 $(( partEnd ))s 100%
sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

mkfs.ext4 "${dev}p${partNumPersistNew}"

sync
sleep 1

e2fsck -v -y -f "${dev}p${partNumPersistNew}"

sync
sleep 1

losetup -d "${dev}"
losetup -D

sync
sleep 1

dd status=progress if=${rootImgFile} >> ${imgFile}
dd status=progress if=${zeroDev} bs=1b count=64 >> ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

dev=$(losetup -f)
losetup -P "${dev}" ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

partEnd=$(sfdisk -s -l -o End "${dev}" | tail -1)
partEnd=$(( partEnd + 1 ))

sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}
parted -s -a opt "${dev}" mkpart primary ext4 $(( partEnd ))s 100%
sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

losetup -d "${dev}"
losetup -D

sync
sleep 1

dev=$(losetup -f)
losetup -P "${dev}" ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

dd status=progress if=${rootImgFile} of="${dev}p${partNumRootNew}"

sync
sleep 1

losetup -d "${dev}"
losetup -D

sync
sleep 1

dev=$(losetup -f)
losetup -P "${dev}" ${imgFile}

sync
sleep 1

sfdisk -s -l "${dev}"

e2fsck -v -y -f "${dev}p${partNumPersistNew}"
e2fsck -v -y -f "${dev}p${partNumRootNew}"
```

Outcome:

...

(S)fdisk output:

```
sfdisk -s -l ${imgFile}
+ sfdisk -s -l original.img

Disk original.img: 3.5 GiB, 3743791104 bytes, 7312092 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xddbefb06

Device        Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
original.img1 *       2048  526335  524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
original.img2       526336 1026047  499712  244M 83 Linux
original.img3      1026048 7311359 6285312    3G 83 Linux
```

Check partition 2:

```
e2fsck -v -y -f "${dev}p${partNumPersistNew}"
+ e2fsck -v -y -f /dev/loop5p2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

          11 inodes used (0.02%, out of 62464)
           0 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
           0 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 3
        6122 blocks used (9.80%, out of 62464)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

           0 regular files
           2 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
           0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
           2 files
```

Check partition 3:

```
e2fsck -v -y -f "${dev}p${partNumRootNew}"
+ e2fsck -v -y -f /dev/loop5p3

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 785703 blocks
The physical size of the device is 501864 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes
```

So it seems that the partition is not reecognized due to the "dummy" partition specs that was made to clone the real partition over onto.

Is this kind of operation doable with some small adjustments, should it be done in a totally different way or would it be even possible to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The idea actually worked. I found a fix to the problem.

The only problem was that I was cloning the partition with option conv=sparse which used holes in place of nul blocks which screw up the partition clone image file.

To fix this, I just had to change the command to make a perfect clone, changing:

```
dd status=progress conv=sparse if="${dev}p${partNumRoot}" of=${rootImgFile}
```

simply into this:

```
dd status=progress if="${dev}p${partNumRoot}" of=${rootImgFile}
```